# Ubuntu, sending file through bluetooth

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, crontab

I want to send a file named `read.txt` using command: `bluetooth-sendto`. It works using the direct command on terminal `bluetooth-sendto --device=MACADDR path/to/read.txt`. I want to execute it with this cron job:

```
*/1 * * * * bluetooth-sendto --device=MACADDR path/to/read.txt
```

But it doesn't work. Redirecting the output of this command results an empty file:

```
*/1 * * * * bluetooth-sendto --device=MACADDR path/to/read.txt>path/to/err.log
```

Permissions of directories and files are 777. Cronjob is settled for same user that can execute command from command line directly. I also tried `sudo crontab -e`, but it didn't work.

From the cron log file:

```
Jun 16 14:26:01 localhost CRON[2023]: (user) CMD (bluetooth-sendto --device=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx /home/user/read.txt)
Jun 16 14:26:01 localhost CRON[2016]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Answer (score 2):

`bluetooth-send` is a GUI application and does not work in headless or without a X connection address.

I recommend that you use `ussp-push`.
The command will be something like `ussp-push 12:34:56:78:9A:BC@ localname remotename`