# send a file via bluetooth from the command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I'm working with the command prompt and I would like to send a file to my phone. Is it possible to send a file via bluetooth from the command prompt?

Comment: Command prompt - Windows

Comment: Tags updated...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Is it possible to send a file via bluetooth from the command prompt?

Yes, it is possible. See below for Windows, Ubuntu and Linux solutions.

---

#### Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 or Windows 10 (x86, x64)

Use [btobex](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/btobex.html).

> Bluetooth command line tools are a suite of command line utilities for
>   Microsoft Windows that can be used to configure your bluetooth
>   adapter, discover remote bluetooth devices and services, transfer
>   files to OBEX capable devices.
>
> All utilities can be invoked as a part of a batch script or other
>   automated background process or launched manually from the Windows
>   command prompt.

...

> System requirements
>
> - Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 or Windows 10 (x86, x64)
> - Microsoft bluetooth stack compatible Bluetooth adapter

Source [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/)

> Btobex sends files to remote OBEX capable devices (computers, mobile phones, etc).
>
> usage:
>
> ```
> btobex {-bBluetoothAddress | -nFriendlyName} [-cChannel] [-pPIN [-e]] 
>          [-rRetries] [-fFileName] [file1 [file2 [...]]] 
>
>     -b  Bluetooth address of target device in (XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX) format.  
>     -n  Friendly name of target device.
>     -c  RFCOMM channel (1-30). If specified, service lookup is not performed. 
>     -p  PIN code for authenticating with remote device.
>     -e  Use encrypted connection (only if PIN authentication is used)
>     -r  Make specified number of attempts is case of error
>     -f  Use this file name for the data from STDIN (standard input)      
>     -h  Prints help screen.
> ```
>
> samples:
>
> 1. Send file "picture.jpg" from the current folder to the device named "Nokia 6300" :
>
>    ```
>    btobex -n"Nokia 6300" picture.jpg
>    ```
> 2. Send all text files from the current folder to the device with known address :
>
>    ```
>    btobex -b(11:11:22:22:33:33) *.txt
>    ```
> 3. Send output of other program as a file named "message.txt" :
>
>    ```
>    echo This is a test | btobex -b(11:11:22:22:33:33) -f"message.txt"
>    ```
>
> btobex maintains the ERRORLEVEL environment variable. Zero means successful execution, any other value - error. Detailed error description is printed to the standard error output.

Source [btobex](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/btobex.html)

---

#### Ubuntu

Use [bluetooth-sendto](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bluetooth-sendto).

> `bluetooth-sendto --device=12:34:56:78:9A:BC filename` works for me.
>
> "12:34:56:78:9A:BC" is the Bluetooth device address (bdaddr) of the device. You can get the bdaddr with `hcitool scan`.

Source [Bluetooth file transfer in shell script](https://askubuntu.com/a/41050/376050), answer by [elmicha](https://askubuntu.com/users/16134/elmicha)

---

#### Linux

Use [obexftp](http://dev.zuckschwerdt.org/openobex/wiki/ObexFtp).

> `obexftp –nopath –noconn –uuid none –bluetooth <BTAddr> –channel
>   <OPUSHChann elNo> –put <FileToPut>`
>
> - Allows one to send file without specifying the pin on the remote device side
> - The OPush channel number for device is got from sdptool above
>
> `obexftp -b <BTAddr> -v -p <FileToPut>`
>
> - Allows one to put a file onto the specified BT device
> - obexftp could also be used to get or list the files on the BT device
> - also allows one to identify a nearby BT device by just giving -b option

Source [Low-level bluetooth utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93626/95111), answer by [slm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm)

See also [Linux script for Bluetooth operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352885/linux-script-for-bluetooth-opertation)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Bluetooth Command Line Tools](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/) in any way.

Comment: Why is Ubuntu solution separate from Linux one? Won't obexftp work in Ubuntu or bluetooth-sendto on a non-Ubuntu Linux distribution?

Comment: You might want to include the note in the comments to the Ubuntu answer, in your answer's Ubuntu section. Other than that, great answer. Related - https://superuser.com/questions/1090009/ubuntu-sending-file-through-bluetooth

Comment: @Ruslan No idea. I don't use either of them.

Comment: You don't use either, but these constitute 2/3rds of your answer? Have you at least witnessed them working, or is this just hearsay?

Comment: @mickeyf One source is an accepted answer on AskUbuntu, the other is a highly upvoted answer from a Unix & Linux mod. The Windows one I have used myself.